# Different of Files.copy and Files.write it seems both methods do the same thing , both methods save a Multipart file to a specific location

Tags: java

Im working on a project and I tried to save a multipart file to my local disk, I tried Both Files.write and Files.copy, Both those methods did my work , can someone explain what is the different between these two ? According to Oracle docs copy method Copies all bytes from an input stream to a file. and write method Writes bytes to a file. can some one give clear definition? Thanks.

[Javadoc for Files class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)

Comment: The `copy()` methods copy entire files or streams. The `write()` method write bytes or lines. All this is stated in the Javadoc. None of them has anything to do with multiparts. Unclear what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't simply replace `copy` with `write` in your code, right?  They aren't interchangeable because they take different arguments. `Files.copy` reads from an `InputStream` and writes the results to a file.  `Files.write` writes the contents of a byte array or a list of character sequences to a file.  So the two do something similar, but they work from different kinds of input.  Although an `InputStream` can pull from an in-memory buffer, the way I look at this is that `write` is always writing something that's already in memory, where `copy` is generally reading bytes from some external source (another file or something coming in from the network) and then writing them to a file.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `Files.copy()` takes an `InputStream` or a `Path` as the source for the bytes to write, while `Files.write()` expects the bytes to write in an array of bytes.

It is a bit awkward that for `copy()` the first parameter is the source, and the second denotes the target, while for `write()` it is the other way round.

Basically, you could say that `Files.copy( Path source, Path target )` is implemented as

```
public static long copy( Path source, Path target )
{
    var bytes = Files.readAllBytes( source );
    Files.write( target, bytes );
    return bytes.size;
}
```

or

```
public static long copy( Path source, Path target )
{
    var bytes = Files.readAllBytes( source );
    Files.copy( new ByteInputStream( bytes ), target );
    return bytes.size;
}
```

(Error handling omitted for brevity! And the real implementation may differ as well!)

From the result, both implementations are equivalent, but the second requires the additional `InputStream` as the wrapper for the array of bytes …

In general, you can say that you use `Files.copy()` if the input data is not (yet) completely hold in memory, otherwise `Files.write()`. With classes like `ByteInputStream`, you can hide that the data this in fact in memory.